# How can I apply the YUI security vulnerability patch on my deployed application using Orbeon Forms?

Tags: xforms, orbeon

Yahoo! released a [security patch](http://yuilibrary.com/support/2.8.2/#dropins) for all the applications using YUI. As Orbeon Forms uses YUI, how can I apply this patch on the version of Orbeon Forms that I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are safe and don't need to patch Orbeon Forms if you are using a version of Orbeon Forms released on or after October 25, 2010 (the day the security vulnerability and patch was announced).

If you are using an earlier build:

1. Unzip the file `WEB-INF/lib/orbeon-resources-public.jar` in a temporary directory.
2. In that directory, open `ops/yui/yahoo/yahoo.js`. Towards the top of the file, you'll see a version number (e.g. 2.6.0). This tells you what version of YUI your build of Orbeon Forms uses.
3. From the [YUI page about this security vulnerability](http://yuilibrary.com/support/2.8.2/#dropins), download the patches for the version of YUI used by your build of Orbeon Forms.
4. Apply the patches by replacing the `swf` files in the temporary directory by those in the patches you downloaded. The YUI file are located under `ops/yui` in your temporary directory.
5. Just in case, make a copy of the `WEB-INF/lib/orbeon-resources-public.jar` in your Orbeon Forms build.
6. Zip the content of your temporary directory into a file called `orbeon-resources-public.jar` and move it to `WEB-INF/lib` in your Orbeon Forms build, replacing the existing copy of that file with the version you created.

Comment: Are you sure this is fixed? Looking at Orbeon 4.9.0 CE, the MD5 of uploader.swf in orbeon-resources-private/ops/yui/uploader is 967bec3a39d75872c1813db9198f90ef. According to the [YUI page](http://yuilibrary.com/support/20121030-vulnerability/#dropins), this is the unpatched variant of version 2.8.2. Does this mean that the patch still has to be applied manually?

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is puzzling. The (ancient) version of YUI being used is 2.8.1, but the MD5 of uploader.swf corresponds to unpatched 2.8.2, according to the page you point to. This file was updated in the following Oct 25, 2010 commit: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/0d02adf6a0041676fa564b0ccba4360160915d11.

Comment: Now, I wouldn't really be worried about it, since this file won't be included in a page by Orbeon Forms. In fact no Flash from YUI will ever be included. Recently, we even removed code that never ran but that could have included a swf (https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/721e42d84148343b916280bba7682ce952cf9693). In addition to that, I think we should just remove the YUI swf files. Would that make you feel better ;)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply & the explanation - and yes, it would! :)

Comment: @sschwieb Then it's decided: we'll just remove those YUI .swf files.

Comment: @sschwieb You you go: those files are now removed, and this change will be in 4.11. Thank you letting us know about this! https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2535